# Browsing to localhost not working after Apache installed

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I have installed Apache, and then I tried writing `http://localhost/` in the browser. It's not working and saying page not found. But, `http://127.0.0.1/` works.

What problem do I have, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried with at least 2 browsers?

Comment: nup and got my answer from john

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be that your hosts file does not map `localhost` to the loopback IP (127.0.0.1). On Windows, your `hosts` file should be at `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. On *NIX, it should be at `/etc/hosts`. Check those files and verify that `localhost` is mapped to the loopback IP. If not, add it.

Here are some resources that might help you. Take a look.

- Linux:
  http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts
- Windows:
  http://accs-net.com/hosts/how_to_use_hosts.html

Comment: Note, newer versions of Windows do the localhost mapping (for both IPv4 and IPv6) in the DNS client, so the entry in `hosts` is correctly commented out.